is there any better and simpler method to evaluate this??
Taotao wants to buy a bracelet. The bracelets have 7 different beads on them, arranged in a
circle. If she can choose the colors and placement of the beads, and the beads come in orange,
white, and black, how many possible bracelets can she buy?
this question is from PUMAC 2009 and the solution uses burnside lemma but can this be solved with some simple combinatorics method ?
my approach-  every bead has 3 options so $3^7$ in total but im stuck in the ordering cuz we know if all objects are distinct then there are $\frac{(n-1)!}{2}$ ways to arrange them but what do we here?
PS- forgive im not used to the formatting how the question is to be sent here but im working on it so please.

Did you have trouble with the Burnside Lemma proof? That is certainly how I would think to solve this.

@healynr "can this be solved with some simple combinatorics method ?"

@SineoftheTime I was wondering why Burnside's Lemma did not count as a simple combinatorics method.

@healynr maybe OP can clarify

@SineoftheTime   no i mean putting in simple terms im a high school student and as much i read about it its related to something called group theory , i might not have asked for a simpler method but it came in pumac which is a high school contest, if u cant help me with it then i have a request can u pls explain me the solution in simple terms?

(Implicitly use Burnside's lemma) Show that if we assume order is important, then apart from the single color bracelet, each bracelet will appear 14 times. Hence, the number of distinct unordered bracelets is $(3^7 - 3 ) / 14 + 3$. $\quad$ (I removed the linear algebra tag)

@CalvinLin yah ik its not linear algebra but yk u have to put 5 tags so i added linear algebra sorry for that um and one more thing the answer is given to be 198 but from yours its coming 159

@AlokRajSingh You do not have to put 5 tags. You have to put at least 1, and can put up to 5. In general, use tags that are appropriate to the question.

Do we consider that ABBBCCC is similar to ACCCBBB ?

@Lourrran yah we have to consider rotation and reflections as same ,so they are similar

What's the plus of relaxing capitals letters?

This question is your best question imo.

@BobDobbs actually I've many question in  which I need help help in but the fact that I do not know how to write in LaTeX is stopping me, although I have started learning and practising it from today.

This solution could be obtained independently via the double-counting technique. Burnside's lemma is implicitly the motivation, but the knowledge of the lemma isn't crucial to understanding this solution.
Show the following

Consider all of the bracelets where order is important. We can represent this a string of 7 values, and there are $3^7$ of them.

Given that order and reflection isn't important, how many times does a bracelet appear?


We count according to the color pattern. For a bracelet, each letter is the same color, and could be identical to a different letter.

If a bracelet can be obtained via rotation, it is of the form AAAAAAA, and hence can also be obtained via reflection: Counted 1 time. There are 3 of them.
If a bracelet can be obtained via reflection but not rotation, then it is of the form ABCDDCB, but not AAAAAAA : Counted 7 times. There are $3^4-3$ of them.
If a bracelet cannot be obtained via reflection or rotation, then it's the remaining ones (prove this) : Counted 14 times. Let there be $k$ of them.


Applying double counting,  $ 1 \times 3 + 7 \times (3^4-3) + 14 \times k = 3^7$, which gives us $k = 117$.

Hence, the number of distinct unordered bracelets is $3 + (3^4 - 3) + 117 = 198$.
Burnside's lemma gives us $ \frac{ 3^7 + 6 \times 3 + 7 \times 3^4 } { 14} = 198$. To see the equivalence to this solution, replace $3^7$ with the equation, and observe that each bracelet is counted 14 times.




im grateful for your solution but are we missing some cases? beacause your answer from the official solution differs   https://static1.squarespace.com/static/570450471d07c094a39efaed/t/58b08fc637c581bd4b6cbca0/1487966151033/PUMaC2009_CombinatoricsASol.pdf  PROBLEM 8  please do have a look at offical solution and if possible please explain why are the answers differing

@AlokRajSingh I spoke too quickly. They are correct. I've updated my solution.

@AlokRajSingh I think this is right, but I have to recommend that you try to understand Burnside's Lemma; it will teach you the motivation behind this type of reasoning and is applicable to many other problems.

The cycle-index polynomial of the dihedral group $D_7$ of $7$-gon is
$$P_{D_7}(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7)=\frac1{14}(x_1^7+7x_1x_2^3+6x_7)$$
and according to Polya theory, the answer of the problem above is
$$P_{D_7}(3,3,3,3,3,3,3)=\frac{3^7+7\times3^4+6\times3}{14}=198.$$
Source: de Brujin's COMBINATORICS, a nice lecture notes book I found in the internet free.
